# or query with include

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a join table with a from column and a to column. Both columns point to user objects. When perform this `OR` query, it throws the error: 'OR queries do not support sub-queries with includes'

Is there any way around this? Thanks!

// set up query to get all relationships where the current user friended another user.

```
PFQuery *userIsFriendSender = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserRelationships"];
[userIsFriendSender whereKey:@"from" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[userIsFriendSender whereKey:@"active" equalTo:@YES];

[userIsFriendSender includeKey:@"to"];

// set up query to get all relationships where a use friended the current user
PFQuery *userIsFriendReceiver = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserRelationships"];
[userIsFriendReceiver whereKey:@"to" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[userIsFriendReceiver whereKey:@"active" equalTo:@YES];

[userIsFriendReceiver includeKey:@"from"];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[userIsFriendSender, userIsFriendReceiver]];
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try moving `includeKey:` clauses to the joint query.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[userIsFriendSender, userIsFriendReceiver]];
[query includeKey:@"from"];
[query includeKey:@"to"];
```